Show arbitrary intersection of partial orders is a uniquely determined partial order

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a relation defined on set $X$, and let $\Omega(\mathcal{A})$ be the set of all supersets of $\mathcal{A}$ that are partial orders. Define $$P(\mathcal{A})=\bigcap_{\mathcal{B}\in\Omega(\mathcal{A})}\mathcal{B}$$ and suppose $\Omega(\mathcal{A})$ is non-empty. Show that $P(\mathcal{A})\in\Omega(\mathcal{A})$ and is uniquely determined.

I’ve approached the first part of this question by taking two arbitrary elements of $\Omega(\mathcal{A})$ and noting that since they are partial orders on $X$, their intersection must also be partial orders on $X$, and proved in a similar way that their intersection must be a superset of $\mathcal{A}$. However I know that properties of finite intersection does not necessarily extend to arbitrary intersection, so I would like some insight as to how to carry on this logic to go from finite to arbitrary. Thanks

The insight I'd offer is that if $\Omega(\mathcal A)$ is non-empty, it's the transitive closure of $\mathcal A$.
